# Juntar elementos de uma lista, com o último separador diferente

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

**Um exercício de um livro que estou estudando tem seguinte questão:**

Suponha que você tenha um valor de lista como:

```
spam = ['apples,'bananas','tofu','cats]
```

Crie uma função que aceite um valor de lista como argumento e retorne uma string com todos os itens separados por uma vírgula e um espaço, com "and" inserido antes do último item.

Por exemplo, se passarmos a lista `spam` anterior à função,`apples, bananas, tofu and cats` será retornado. Porém sua função deverá ser capaz de trabalhar com qualquer valor de lista que ela receber.

Pensei na seguinte resolução:

```
spam = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']
def string(lista):
    cont = 0
    for i in lista:
        if cont < (len(lista))-2:
            print(i +',',end=' ')
            cont +=1
        elif cont == (len(lista))-2:
            print(i +' and',end=' ')
            cont +=1
        else:
            print(i)
            cont+=1
```

De princípio ela resolve meu problema, mas haveria alguma forma de escrever esse código de uma maneira mais limpa?

Comment: Olá renan... considere deixar o titulo com uma leitura manos macro. Ou seja, tente ser mais específico em suas perguntas, isso é para evitar Banimento na plataforma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apenas complementando as outras respostas, seguem algumas outras opções.

Primeiro uma solução similar à [resposta do Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/421692/112052), mas verificando os casos em que a lista é vazia ou só contém um elemento (afinal, o exercício diz que "a função deverá ser capaz de trabalhar com qualquer valor de lista", então devemos considerar esses casos também):

```
def juntar(lista):
    if not lista:
        return ''
    if len(lista) == 1:
        return lista[0]

    s = ', '.join(lista[:-1])
    return f'{s} and {lista[-1]}'

print(juntar(['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats'])) # apples, bananas, tofu and cats
print(juntar(['apples', 'bananas'])) # apples and bananas
print(juntar(['apples'])) # apples
print(juntar([])) # não imprime nada (somente uma linha em branco)
```

Primeiro eu uso `if not lista` para verificar se a lista é vazia (isso funciona porque [uma lista vazia é considerado um valor falso](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)). Entendo que se a lista é vazia, a string correspondente deve ser "nada" (ou seja, a string vazia: `''`), já que não há o que concatenar.

Depois eu vejo o caso em que a lista só tem um elemento, pois neste caso não deve ter nenhuma vírgula e nem o  `and`  (por exemplo, se a lista for `['apples']`, então a string resultante deve ser somente `apples`). Neste caso, basta retornar o primeiro - e único - elemento da lista.

Se a lista tiver mais de um elemento, aí eu uso o algoritmo já proposto: uso [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) para juntar do primeiro ao penúltimo elemento, separados por vírgula mais o espaço (`lista[:-1]` usa a [sintaxe de *slice*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295) para criar uma outra lista, contendo do primeiro ao penúltimo elemento).

Em seguida eu uso uma [*f-string*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) para juntar esta string com o texto "and" mais o último elemento da lista (as *f-strings* estão disponíveis a partir do Python 3.6 mas se estiver usando uma versão anterior, pode usar [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) conforme já sugerido [na resposta do Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/421692/112052)).

---

Outra opção é usar `join` para juntar todos os elementos separados por vírgula, e depois você substitui a última vírgula por "and":

```
def juntar(lista):
    s = ', '.join(lista)
    i = s.rfind(', ')
    if i < 0:
        return s
    return f'{s[:i]} and {s[i + 2:]}'

print(juntar(['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats'])) # apples, bananas, tofu and cats
print(juntar(['apples', 'bananas'])) # apples and bananas
print(juntar(['apples'])) # apples
print(juntar([])) # não imprime nada (somente uma linha em branco)
```

Primeiro faço um `join`, e o resultado será uma string contendo todos os elementos separados por vírgula e espaço. Depois eu uso [`rfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) para obter o índice da última ocorrência de `', '`.

Se nenhuma vírgula + espaço for encontrada, `rfind` retorna `-1`, e neste caso, quer dizer que a lista tinha um elemento ou era vazia, então eu posso retornar o resultado do `join` sem modificações.

Mas se o índice for encontrado, ele corresponde à última ocorrência de `', '`. Então eu crio outra string contendo tudo até esta última ocorrência (`s[:i]` - novamente usando a sintaxe de *slice* para obter um pedaço da string), junto com "and" e com todo o trecho da string depois da última ocorrência da vírgula (`s[i + 2:]` - somo `2` para que não pegue a vírgula nem o espaço).

O único problema desta solução é quando o último elemento contém uma vírgula seguida de espaço. Por exemplo, se a lista for `['apples', 'bananas, cats']`, o resultado será `apples, bananas and cats` - mas está errado, pois a última vírgula é a que faz parte da string `'bananas, cats'` e não deveria ser substituída. Usando o primeiro código, obtém-se o resultado correto (`apples and bananas, cats` - afinal, a vírgula entre "bananas" e "cats" faz parte da string e não deve ser substituída).

Comment: Bem jogado, esqueci-me da eventualidade de a lista estar vazia ou com apenas um elemento

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer omitindo o ciclo:

```
def join_list(lista):
     str = ', '.join(lista[:-1]) # gerar uma string com os items separados por virgula, com excecao do ultimo
     return '{} and {}'.format(str, lista[-1]) # adicionar o ultimo com 'and' e retornar

spam = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']
print(join_list(spam)) # apples, bananas, tofu and cats
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/CautiousFrozenCommunication)

Answer (score 1):

Estou lendo o mesmo livro e iniciando no Python, acredito que surgirão outros usuários com a mesma dúvida. Tendo em vista o pouco conhecimento até aqui adquirido, meu programa ficou assim:

```py
spam = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats'] # a lista apresentada no livro
def separar(item):
        frase = '' #criei uma string em branco para ir acrescentando os valores
        for i in range(int(len(item) -2)): #defini o limite da inserção das palávras na frase
            frase = frase + item[i] #somei a frase em branco item por item 
            frase = frase + ', ' #acresentei a virgula a partir do primeiro item     
            print(frase + item[-2] + ' and ' + item[-1]) # acrescentei os dois ultimos itens separadamente pois não entraram na contágem anterior.
separar(spam) #acrescentei a lista spam na função separar.
```

Quebrei bastante a cabeça nesse exercício, mas valeu o aprendizado. Espero que a resposta esclareça mais pessoas.